# how to display the selected node from the treeview in the textbox?

Tags: c#

Hi im having treeview with checkbox and 1 submit button it is taking values from database.

now if i check the checkbox and click the submit button it should display the selected node in the textbox.....

here is my treeview code

```
public void Load_tree()
    {
        DataSet PrSet = PDataset("SELECT * FROM tbl_saleschannelhierarchyconfig");
        TreeView1.Nodes.Clear();
        foreach (DataRow dr in PrSet.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            if ((int)dr["ParentID"] == 0)
            {
                TreeNode tnParent = new TreeNode();
                tnParent.Text = dr["Parent"].ToString();
                string value = dr["ParentID"].ToString();
                //tnParent.Text = dr["SalesChannelName"].ToString(); - if u use this   instead of the previous two lines, then "kmart" will be the parent. else "root" will be the parent.
                //string value = dr["SalesChannelConfigID"].ToString();
                tnParent.Expand();
                TreeView1.Nodes.Add(tnParent);
                FillChild(tnParent, value);
            }
        }
    }       
    public int FillChild(TreeNode parent, string SalesChannelConfigID)
    { 
        DataSet ds = PDataset("SELECT * FROM tbl_saleschannelhierarchyconfig WHERE   ParentID =" + SalesChannelConfigID); 
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                TreeNode child = new TreeNode(); 
                child.Text = dr["SalesChannelName"].ToString().Trim(); 
                string temp = dr["SalesChannelConfigID"].ToString(); 
                child.Collapse();
                parent.ChildNodes.Add(child);
                FillChild(child, temp); 
            }
            return 0;
        } 
        else
        { 
            return 0; 
        }
```

and button click code

```
   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        txtRetailCustomerGroup.Text = TreeView1.SelectedNode.Parent.ToString();
    }
```

it is showing this exception 
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

can any1 help me??

Comment: What line is throwing the exception? Does it happen only on clicking the button?

Comment: The question is whether the treeview is null, the selected node is null, or the parent is null

Comment: also, when debugging, can you see all nodes actually in the tree?

Comment: @SkonJeet txtRetailCustomerGroup.Text = TreeView1.SelectedNode.Parent.ToString();

Comment: See my answer - the problem is one of 4 things.

Comment: @Yorye nullreference exception ..s its showing al the nodes

Comment: @YoryeNathan - could also be the txtRetailCustomerGroup that's null.

Comment: @SkonJeet true, but its probably the selected node or the parent, because the rest is most likely design time stuff for him, unless he screwed with them in the code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to 'do something' with an object that hasn't be instantiated basically. For you to do this certain something with something in memory - you use an object as a reference to it's location in memory. You're using an object that has no reference to a position in memory (no actual "physical" object), so it can't run the code.

If it only happens when you're clicking the button (i.e. the problem is in the event handler you've posted), it'll either be the txtRetailCustomerGroup (so it can't access text) or it'll be the TreeView1, SelectedNode, or Parent of that selected node (and so therefore can't convert to string).

Use breakpoints to have a quick look into the objects (to find the one that isn't instantiated) and it should become evident where the null object is. Then you have to figure out why.

Comment: i think my button code is having some problem can u send me the correct code to display th selected node in the textbox

Comment: `txtRetailCustomerGroup.Text = TreeView1.SelectedNode.Text.ToString();` - displaying the selected node in the text box is not what you originally set out to do judging by the code in your OP. And you also have to cater for the case where no node is selected.

Answer (score 1):

Until you learn how to use **breakpoints**,

Use this as your button function:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("txt={0}\r\ntv={1}\r\nsn={2}",
                                  txtRetailCustomerGroup,
                                  TreeView1,
                                  TreeView1 == null ? "." : TreeView1.SelectedNode));

    txtRetailCustomerGroup.Text = TreeView1.SelectedNode.Parent.ToString();
}
```

Run this once and let us know what the message box the pops up says. This will clear things up.

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        txtRetailCustomerGroup.Text = TreeView1.SelectedNode.Parent.ToString();
    }
```

if You select main root node, it has not parent so it returns this error

if change like this, it will run succesfully

```
 txtRetailCustomerGroup.Text = TreeView1.SelectedNode.Text.ToString();
```

else try this

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try{
                txtRetailCustomerGroup.Text = TreeView1.SelectedNode.Parent.ToString();
             }
             catch{}
    }
```

Comment: If the problem IS with the treeview - then taking the text of the selected node will give an entirely different result to converting the parent node to string. This doesn't really solve his problem. If you're right about the cause of the error then yes it's a good idea to deal with the case of selecting a root node, but throwing a try catch around the original line of code won't solve it. I'd code using a more defensive if statement.

Comment: @muslum txtRetailCustomerGroup.Text = TreeView1.SelectedNode.Text.ToString(); this code showing the same exception and try{ txtRetailCustomerGroup.Text = TreeView1.SelectedNode.Parent.ToString(); } catch{} this code no exception but not displayin it in the textbox also

Comment: @vani - you need some structure to your problem solving. What are you even trying to achieve?? On button click show the text of the (if any) selected node in a text box? Is this right?

Comment: +1 for SkonJeet. Vani - as Skon suggested breakpoints, and as it really sounds like you're just typing code and running it, gambling away, I also say - learn debugging using breakpoints and stepping and the watch window, etc. Not only you will solve this faster than we can from right here, and in under 5 minutes, but also its an amazing and powerful tool that any programmer should master.

Comment: @yorye actually i asked for that click function ly know now ly im learnin but i hav to finish this task now den wat ill do?

Comment: "...an amazing and powerful tool that any programmer should master" Spot on. Crucial to programming. I'm only a graduate and already realise it's importance.

Comment: It's upto you when you learn to debug and use breakpoints properly, whether you learn it now (doesn't take long) or shortly is upto you, but you wouldn't have needed to ask this question if you were familiar with it.